# Adding GPIOLIB dependency

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to compile a kernel module which uses the new GPIO API from `linux/gpio/consumer.h`. But the make fails with '`error: ‘gpio_handle’ has an incomplete type ‘struct gpio_desc’'`. I read that I need to additionally include GPIOLIB dependency in Kconfig, but simply adding 'depends on' doesn't work. What is the correct way to include such a dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler than I thought... Just replacing `struct gpio_desc xx` with `struct gpio_desc* xx` fixed the issue, so that the actual struct is allocated at run-time. Consequently this should apply to other cases in kernel with such structs.